# How to track and report which data is used or accessed the most for a site on an internal network?

Tags: views, nodes

I have a Drupal site set up on Solaris 10.

I made custom PHP file to allow users to pass parameters in URL to retrieve feedback in xml format, and a couple of [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display data in table format.

Is there a way to track which data is used or accessed the most and display it in a report? So I can get rid of the data less frequent used.

**Note**: The site I built is for internal network, so the outside world doesn't have access to it (and therefor I cannot use Google Analytics).

Comment: I can't think of a better use for Google Analytics :)

Comment: The module or the site?

Comment: I have a problem with the module. The site I built is for internal network, so outside world don't have access to it.

Comment: Ah ok GA probably won't do the trick then. Why not just set up a simple table with two columns, `type` and `count`. Then in each PHP script you can just increment the counter for that particular format's type in your table, and you've got a record of how many times each different format was requested

Comment: hm, doesn't look like an appealing solution, still prefer more analytic way that I can have some visual representation, and also makes it available in the future development.

Comment: I think this goes beyond a Drupal problem then to be honest; it sounds like you're looking for a local analytics server application of some kind. Maybe [OWA](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) would be of some help

Comment: yea, i was looking for some module would do it, i would use google analytics, but it's on an internal network. still thanks for your help

Comment: OWA isn't working out too well. I don't know if it's me or OWA is trying to access the site externally. I have OWA installed in the same root folder as drupal, and set up the configuration in drupal for OWA as well, but OWA isn't showing any data.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Here are some reports you get from it:

> - View pages that have recently been visited.
> - View pages that have been hit frequently.
> - View pages count per month, day of month, day of week, hour.
> - ...

Especially these reports should be what you're looking for, which also **includes hits for paths corresponding to a view**, such as the one with path `charts/examples/views`:

- [Top pages](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/top_pages.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Title, Path and nr of Hits). Here is an example of this report:

  [image]
- [Recent hits](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/recent_hits.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Date of visit, Title, Path and User ID of the visitor). Here is an example of this report:

  [image]

  If you follow any of the "details" links in the example above, you'll get something that looks as in this example:

  [image]

Checkout the above (source) links to get an idea of which data are available.

The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also. Any visits to a Views related path will be reported in the **Recent hits** module. This demo site also shows some additional blocks with reports also created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module module.

You may also want to look at the [visitors_schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.install?h=7.x-2.x#n37) to get an idea of the data that actually get logged (recorded) by this module.

In case it's not a perfect fit, it's probably a very good starting point for some custom reporting. Either via a custom module that would simply have to query the data maintained by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Or via a straight forward custom report created with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

<sup>Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module,
and co-maintainer of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.</sup>