# Visitor Counter

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way of finding out the number visitors of a drupal website, where they go to and where they are from. Google Analytics come to mind (or if any other module can do a better job).

Comment: Maybe something like in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/161888/39516)? Or maybe something similar to what is shown on [this site](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors)?

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to track user interactions with forms/nodes/etc you might want to look into Events Log Track - https://www.drupal.org/project/events_log_track

With that said adding Google Analytics is also super easy via the module. https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics

*** Edited to comment on  Visitors module as there appears to be a bug that was introduced into it in D8*** You might also want to keep an eye on the visitors module I used it with great success in D7 . It's available in D7 and D8, but there appears to be a bug mentioned with the D8 install that is being worked on. - https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors.